# Customizing navigation view items

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, customization, android-navigationview

I want to create a custom navigation view with changing default padding of navigation view items according to my design. While changing the same I try to apply custom styles with my required padding value to navigation view But while applying, it changes whole navigation view include header But what I want is to apply different padding values to different groups of menu items according to my design.

Here is My design

[image]

Like you see from images that top group have different left padding than that of bottom group. How to change this or I have to use listview within navigation view.

Answer (score 0):

you can customize your navigation view like this way

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
           android:src="@drawable/dirghhome"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lst_menu_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
          <Textview> 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
          <LinearLayout...........</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```